# how to modify label grid into buttons

Tags: python, tkinter

It's written to be a phone dial and I need to make each of the numbers into buttons and then print the numbers that have been clicked on.

```
from tkinter import Tk, Label, RAISED
root = Tk()
labels = [['1', '2', '3'],
          ['4', '5', '6'],
          ['7', '8', '9'],
          ['*', '0', '#']]
for r in range(4):
    for c in range(3):
        #create label for row r and column c
        label = Label(root,
                      relief=RAISED,
                      padx=15,
                      text=labels[r][c])
        #place label in row r and column c
        label.grid(row=r, column=c)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason you're using a `Label` widget rather than a `Button`?

Comment: It's like a 2 part question, the first problem wanted me to make a phone dial using a label grid and the second asks to make them buttons

Answer (score 1):

Use `Button(... , command=lambda x=some_value: some_function(x) )`

```
from tkinter import Tk, Label, RAISED

labels = [['1', '2', '3'],
          ['4', '5', '6'],
          ['7', '8', '9'],
          ['*', '0', '#']]


def my_function(text):
    print(text)


root = Tk()

for r in range(4):
    for c in range(3):
        #create button for row r and column c
        Button(root,
              relief=RAISED,
              padx=15,
              command=lambda x=labels[r][c]: my_function(x),
              text=labels[r][c]).grid(row=r, column=c)

root.mainloop()
```